# Replace Symfony service in tests for php 7.2

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, php-7.2

I'm trying to upgrade my application working on Symfony 3.3 and php 7.1 to php 7.2, but I encountered tons of DEPRECATED messages when I run phpunit. Most annoying is:

**The "user.user_service" service is already initialized, replacing it is deprecated since Symfony 3.3 and will fail in 4.0: 7x**

This is because I have this lines at setUp method:

```
$this->userService = $this->getMockBuilder(UserService::class)
    ->setMethods(['update'])
    ->getMock();
$container->set('user.user_service', $this->userService);
```

7x is because I have 7 test cases at that class, and setUp is fired for each of them. How could I handle this issue? I can't remove this mock because it's important.

I can't understand why Symfony point exactly to this testcase, because I have lots of services replaced this way across all my tests. I don't replace  this service anywhere before this setUp method, so it's strange.

Comment: Can you show how you are initializing your container?

Comment: @Jason Roman, Sure, I use `$container = static::$kernel->getContainer();`

Comment: Can you update the question in one complete test case, please?

Comment: You could try this: `$this->container->getDefinition('user.user_service')->setSynthetic(true);` before doing your `$container->set` call.

Answer (score 1):

So, after build the container, container's immutable and you can't add other services/parameters to it (replace too, because this contain two operation - delete and set).

But, in more cases we should have any opportunities for replace logic inside a our service.

For this, I use custom services only for tests. This service override default service (`class TestUserService extends UserService`) or use interfaces (better). After create class I declare this service with same name in `app/config/test.yml (when@test)` or via another opportunities.

```
namespace Acme;

interface UserServiceInterface
{
    public function create(object $some): User;
}

/* Original service */
readonly class UserService implements UserServiceInterface
{
    public function create(object $some): User
    {
        // Some actions here
    }
}

/* Service only for test */
class TestUserService implements UserServiceInterface
{ 
    private ?\Closure $callback;
    
    public function shouldExecute(\Closure $callback): void
    {
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    public function create(object $some): User
    {
        if ($this->callback) {
            return ($this->callback)($some);
        }
        
        throw new \RuntimeException(\sprintf(
            'The service %s wrong configured. Please call "shouldExecute" method previously.',
            __CLASS__
        ));
    }
}
```

And declare it in you config (YAML as an example):

```
services:
    user_service:
        class: Acme\UserService

when@test:
    services:
        user_service:
            class: Acme\TestUserService
```

After this, I can easy use any logic inside `UserService::create` only for test environment.

```
class SomeTest extends TestCase
{
    private TestUserService $userService;
    
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->userService = self::getContainer()->get('user_service');
    }
    
    public function shouldSuccess(): void
    {
        $this->userService->shouldExecute(static function (object $some) {
            self::assertEquals('foo bar', $some);
            
            return new User();
        });
        
        // logic for testing
    }
}
```

In few cases, developer want to have opportunities to change logic only in specific cases. For this we can use decorator pattern and call origin `UserService` inside `TestUserService` if callback not configured.